# Trying to install Linux Distro on Raid 1

Tags: debian, ubuntu, partition, raid1

I have a system with the following components:

- RAM -> 32GB (swap filed is advisable to be DOUBLE the RAM size so 64/65GB)
- sda -> Samsung 500GB SSD -> Raid disc 1 -> RAID-1 member 0 === soft raid
- sdb -> Samsung 500GB SSD -> Raid disc 2 -> RAID-1 member 1 === soft raid
- sdc -> WD 1TB HDD
- sdd -> Seagate 2TB HDD

#### Goal:

Install Linux distro + apache web + php + mySQL (+ future mail server) onto system. Have system available for web-hosting -> for web-development portfolio.

#### What I've tried already:

As mentioned above I have 2 x 500GB SSD's. SO why not run them in RAID-1. I don't have to, but their available so why not? ok, so its software raid, but if 1 drives fails, at least there's 1 another copy available.

When I first tried install Debian 9.5, I originally set the sda - 500gb SSD, and sdb - 500gb SSD, as RAID 0, in the BIOS. Debian **DID NOT SEE** the drives. Back into BIOS remove RAID, re-start Debian Install -> NOW SEE's DRIVES. I got up and running on my local host. However, after a reboot, I couldn't get into the system any more (password fail). Since nothing on it, I chose to re-install.

This time, I tried the Ubuntu **server** ISO. And here's where all the questions come from: In the ubuntu install sequence. It wanted me to start doing disc partitioning. So it wants me allocate `/boot`, `/home`, `/`, ... I  did the following:

- gave it 1GB for `/boot`, *but I was NOT able to put it on the RAID.*
- In the documentation it said you normally want *DOUBLE your RAM* for swap file size. I have 32GB so double is 64GB. Which I partitioned on both drives in RAID. So I ended up with RAID 1 - 0 -> 64GB (swap file) and the Raid 0 - 1 (435GB) balance for OS/Server, apps.

#### The question:

*How do I put the `/boot` partition on the RAID-1?*

Comment: Hello. Please edit your question to describe your available disk sizes. You've mentioned 65GB swao (ouch) - just how much memory does this box have? And you've also mentioned 1TB and 2TB drives. Are you using hardware RAID or software?

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **;-)**  Could you [edit] your question and ask... erm.. well... one question... per question? Then ping me here @Fabby so I can come back and answer your question.  Now your  question is **too broad**

Comment: @Fabby more details up above - question edited - hopefully it provides clarity

Comment: Please re-read if I understand your issue correctly (Edited) then ping me again.

Comment: @Fabby how do I put /boot partition on Raid-1 - yes, and how do I install a swap file 64GB on Raid-1, and how do I install everything else on the balance of Raid-1, Consider: 500GB available. 1GB - /boot, 64GB - /swap, 435GB -/everything else but all 3 on the SAME Raid-1

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/634482/setting-up-a-bootable-multi-device-raid-1-using-linux-software-raid

Comment: One question per question. [Swap is here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-8tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher/594402#594402)

Answer (score 1):

RAID-0 stripes your data across multiple drives and *is worse than no RAID at all from a reliability perspective* because if one drive fails, the entire array becomes inaccessible and that's why Ubuntu refuses to mount `boot` on a RAID-0 array.

RAID-1 protects your drives by mirroring 2 drives and writing to both at once (slower than no RAID) and reading from both at once (faster).

As the hardware RAID of your RAID Controller does not seem to be recognised by Ubuntu (Probably because it's a BIOS Fake RAID), your only other option is to use a software RAID and this has some disadvantages:

- No Dual boot with another OS (as the software RAID is OS specific)
- All of the RAID processing is done by the system’s CPU instead of the Hardware RAID Controller
- Disk replacement when the RAID fails needs an of-line backup of the configuration data.
- Needs a backup and a restore of the UEFI partition that came with the machine as you're going to wipe both drives.

As you're installing a server ISO, RAID-1 use the following process:

1. Backup the EFI partition using something like [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) just in case you want to go back.
2. Boot the Server ISO until you get to "Partitioning the disk"
3. Choose <kbd>Manual</kbd> for your partitioning method:
   [image: Manual Pärtitioning]
4. Select the first hard drive, and agree to "Create a new empty partition table on this device?".
5. Repeat this step for the next drive that will be part of the RAID array.
6. Select the `Free Space` on the first drive then select <kbd>Create a new partition</kbd>.
7. Select the size of the partition. This partition will be the swap partition, ([have a look here for swap size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-8tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher/594402#594402)) then choose Primary, then Beginning.
8. Select the <kbd>Use as</kbd> line at the top. By default this is `Ext4 journaling file system`, change that to `physical volume for RAID` then <kbd>Done setting up partition</kbd>.
9. For the `/boot` partition once again select `Free Space` on the first drive then <kbd>Create a new partition</kbd>.
10. Use at least 2 GB of the free space on the drive and choose <kbd>Continue</kbd>, then <kbd>Primary</kbd>.
11. As with the swap partition, select the `Use as:` line at the top, changing it to `physical volume for RAID`. Also select the "Bootable flag:" line to change the value to "on". Then choose <kbd>Done setting up partition</kbd>.
12. For the `/` partition once again select `Free Space` on the first drive then <kbd>Create a new partition</kbd>.
13. Use all of the free space on the drive that's left and choose <kbd>Continue</kbd>, then <kbd>Primary</kbd>.
14. Select the `Use as:` line at the top, changing it to `physical volume for RAID`. Then choose <kbd>Done setting up partition<</kbd>.

and then follow normal formatting to format the partitions.

And finally when the system is fully running, **[backup the mdadm config!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458601/backup-existing-mdadm-array-setup)**